# Questions resolved in Comment

Tags: support

What should be the approach to close the question which got resolved in comments, and are of low quality.

By low quality I mean errors arising out of typo, and similar stuff.
e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/25790598/2711647

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a question like that, which was a result of a typo, we have a close reason explicitly for that exact situation, located in the off-topic submenu:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Just because it's resolved in the comments doesn't necessarily mean it needs to be closed. If it's still a valid question and the answer would be useful to others, consider asking the person to move it into a proper answer or answering it yourself.

Considering that whether it's answered in the comments or with an actual answer isn't really relevant at all to whether a question should be closed or not, you seem to just be asking what we should do with low-quality questions. Find the appropriate close reason. If you can't find one that fits, it might not be appropriate to close it.

Comment: Addendum: Negatively voted unanswered questions will be automatically cleaned up.